# XML Interpreter

Tags: xml, interpreter

Is there any Open source XML interpreter developed in C language?
It should accept given xsd files and when some new xml file is provided as buffer or filefd then it should parse and create appropriate memory model and invoke binary transformation libs provided.
XML interpreter should allow user to provide external library to convert the xml to binary representation like xdr,cdr or custom formats?

I want to use it as adapter, we get some rest msg and want to convert to binary msg like sip... I don;t want to use code generation approach even though it is faster.

regards

Answer (score 0):

Try using libXML 2.0: http://www.xmlsoft.org/ it is **the** C XML parser library.

Comment: thanks. If i use libxml way what could be the estimate to develop a interpreter?

Comment: @user1592025 what do you mean by estimate? Time?